# Returning Value from exe using servlet not working

Tags: java, servlets, exe

I am reading the value of an exe file by using servlet as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

  public void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) throws IOException, ServletException {

       PrintWriter out = rs.getWriter();
      String filePath = "C:\\Tomcat 8.0\\webapps\\ROOT\\code\\cpp\\param.exe";
    if (new File(filePath).exists()) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(filePath,"10","13");
        pb.redirectError();
        pb.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        int value = -1;

        while ((value = is.read()) != -1) {

            //out.println("here");
           // System.out.print((char) value);
            out.println(String.valueOf(value));

        }

        int exitCode = p.waitFor();

        out.println(filePath + " exited with " + exitCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    System.err.println(filePath + " does not exist");
}

  }
}
```

The exe file which is actually exe in cpp. The exe will return sum of the numbers 10, 13 using:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(filePath,"10","13");
```

But I am not getting the sum. What I did wrong? I am getting the output as

```
C:\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\code\cpp\param.exe exited with 0
```

But unfortunately not sum. Please help me!!

Comment: When you run the cpp code from command line it print the sum to the console?

Comment: @igreen yes it do when I am using pure java the same program works well. But when I am working with Servlet it is not!!

Comment: Try to remove the redirect lines.

Comment: @igreen I had removed the lines now I am  getting 50 , 51 in two lines as output. Which is wrong it should be 10+13

Comment: this is the right answer: hance you read the answer as number you get the ascii decimal value: 50 is 2 and 51 is 3 that give you 23 the right answer!

Comment: Use `Character.toString()` or bufferdReader as the last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure of it, but it could be a path or environment problem. Because when you start your program from command line, you have a *standard* environment including `PATH` variables. But I suspect Tomcat to build a new environment.

If your exe file (since its name, I assume a C++ executable) uses DLL files and is started with a wrong PATH it could not be able to find them.

How to confirm : just print the path from within the servlet :

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```

Then in a cmd window, set the path to that value and try to execute your program : `C:\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT\code\cpp\param.exe  13 10`

How to fix if problem is confirmed :

- if possible rebuid `param.exe` statically
- wrap `param.exe` in a batch file where first line sets a correct PATH and starts the batch file from your servlet

  ```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CMD.EXE", "/C", batchPath + " 10 13");
  ```

Comment: you can set the env in the `processBuilder` 

    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
    env.remove("OTHERVAR");
    env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");

Answer (score 1):

Few time ago I wrote some code for the same purpose but **using the Runtime class**, may be it can help you:

```
    public int runClient(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String options = "";
        for(String arg : args){
            options+=" "+arg;
        }
        String command ="./StartClient"; #change it with your file path
        command += options;
        System.out.println("Lauching: "+command);
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));

        String line = input.readLine();

        while(true){
            if(line==null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);

            line= input.readLine();
        }

        return process.waitFor();
    }
```

Comparing the code the main difference is in the while loop, may be your program get out of the loop immediately.